# java incrementing with for works only once

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

```
City[] array = new City[6];
String [] arr = {"Paris","London","Rome","Los Angeles","New York","San Francisco"};
int [] arr2 = {200000, 100000, 80000, 60000, 50000, 45000};
String [] arr3 = {"Breitzel", "Statute of Liberty", "Tramways"};

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    if (i<3){
        City V = new City (arr[i], "EU", tab2[i]);
        array[i] = V;
    }

    else {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
            Capitale C = new Capitale (arr[i], "USA", arr2[i], arr3[j]);
            array[i] = C;
        }
    }
}
```

The first incrementing loop works well, the one that creates cities (System.out.printline shows that City[] get 6 elements, which are the 6 cities.

BUT : the 3 American cities should each be assigned an element of arr3. This doesn't work. j doesn't get incremented and all 3 American cities get "Tramways".

I don't see why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the contrary, `j` is being incremented.

But each iteration of the internal loop is overwriting the results of the prior iteration.

The last iteration has j = 2, and `arr3[2]` is "Tramways".

I think you'll get the result you're looking for with this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    if (i<3){
        City V = new City (arr[i], "EU", tab2[i]);
        array[i] = V;
    }
    else {
        Capitale C = new Capitale (arr[i], "USA", arr2[i], arr3[j - 3]);
        array[i] = C;
    }
}
```

That said, the code isn't all that clear. The magic value of 3 isn't clear.

You could address this with a named constant:

```
final int INDEX_OF_FIRST_CAPITALE = 3;
```

Or by having `arr3` be parallel to the other two arrays

```
String [] arr3 = { null, null, null, "Breitzel", "Statute of Liberty", "Tramways"};
```

Or by using a map from capital name to attraction.

```
Map<String,String> = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy ! The solution is that I inverted the creation of Cities and Capitals, as only 3 capitals are created and the first if provides : if i<3.

Comment: @thiebo - That also works! I would recommend defining a named constant for the number of capitals. You could define it with the length of an array, so that it's automatically updated correctly. For example, `final int COUNT_CAPITALES = arr3.length;` By the way, I notice that none of your questions have accepted answers. You can accept an answer as most useful to you by clicking the checkmark to the left of the question.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I thought upvoting the answer did that trick. I accepted your answer. Thanks a lot again for your very precise answer.